# Why is my responsive site not showing up correctly on a mobile browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries, css-grid

I am currently working on a simple responsive portfolio site. I am using HTML and CSS grid to layout the site. Right now it works correctly on a desktop view and even when shrunken down to the smallest size in a desktop browser.

However, when i load the page on my mobile browser (iPhone Xs - chrome and safari) there is empty space to the right of the Nav bar and the images are flowing off the right side of the page. I need it to fit within the page bounds but I am stuck. The media queries I have do not seem to be working and I do not want to have to create a separate mobile HTML and CSS page.

The HTML, CSS and Javascript are below:

```js
const toggleButton = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle-button')[0]
const navbarLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar-links')[0]

toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  navbarLinks.classList.toggle('active')
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.gray {
  background-color: #ebebeb;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  color: #004e98;
  max-width: 1560px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* BRAND TITLE CSS ALL PROPERTIES */

.brand-title {
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  margin: 1rem 1rem 1rem 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  /*     background-color: pink; */
  /*leave margin, it affects space around ur name when mobile size*/
}

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #004e98;
}

a:visited {
  color: #004e98;
}


/* BRAND TITLE CSS ALL PROPERTIES END */

.navbar-links {
  height: 100%;
}

.navbar-links ul {
  display: flex;
  /*makes list horizontal, not vertical*/
  margin-right: 30px;
  padding: 0;
  /*     background-color: yellow; */
}

.navbar-links li {
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar-links li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #004e98;
  padding-left: 2rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.navbar-links li a:hover {
  color: #ff6700;
}

.brand-title a:hover {
  color: #ff6700;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.toggle-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.2rem;
  right: 1rem;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 30px;
  height: 21px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.toggle-button .bar {
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #004e98;
  /* color of individual bars*/
  border-radius: 10px;
}

@media(min-width:600px) {
  .Content {
    display: block;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    margin: 40px auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 699px) {
  .navbar {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
  .toggle-button {
    display: flex;
  }
  .navbar-links {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
  }
  .navbar-links ul {
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-right: 0;
    /*this removes margin applied for large screens*/
  }
  .navbar-links ul li {
    text-align: center;
    /*        background-color: #EC643E;  /*orange bkg color of drop down*/
    */
  }
  .navbar-links ul li a {
    padding: 1rem 1rem;
    /*       border-style: solid; */
    /*       border-radius: 15px; */
    background-color: ;
    /*blue button bkg*/
    margin: 0;
    color: #004e98;
  }
  .navbar-links.active {
    display: flex;
    background-color: #ebebeb;
  }
  .navbar-links li a:hover {
    background-color: #ff6700;
    /*orange bar color upon hover*/
    color: white;
  }
}

.Content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(400px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 10px;
  max-width: 1560px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  /*   background-color: #ffedba; */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 15px;
}


/* IMAGE OVERLAY CSS - START*/

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  /* Black see-through */
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.child-a:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 100;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.child-a {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}


/* IMAGE OVERLAY CSS - END*/


/* Background Styles Only */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway');
* {
  font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<!-- <script type="text/javascript"> -->
<!--
    if (screen.width <= 699) {
    document.location = "mobile.html";
    }
    //-->
<!-- </script> -->

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - Home page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
  <div class="gray">
    <nav class="navbar">
      <div class="brand-title"><a href="#">Your name</a></div>
      <a href="#" class="toggle-button">
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
      </a>
      <div class="navbar-links">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <div class="Content">

    <div class="child-a"><img src="https://greatplainsnursery.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/oak-tree-pic.jpg">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="overlay">
          <div class="text">Tree</div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="child-a"><img src="https://i.insider.com/5cc1bb5766ae8f377d25f087?width=750&format=jpeg&auto=webp">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="overlay">
          <div class="text">Stuff</div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="child-a"><img src="https://greatplainsnursery.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/oak-tree-pic.jpg">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="overlay">
          <div class="text">Tree</div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="child-a"><img src="https://i.insider.com/5cc1bb5766ae8f377d25f087?width=750&format=jpeg&auto=webp">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="overlay">
          <div class="text">Tree</div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="child-a"><img src="https://greatplainsnursery.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/oak-tree-pic.jpg">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="overlay">
          <div class="text">Stuff</div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="child-a"><img src="https://i.insider.com/5cc1bb5766ae8f377d25f087?width=750&format=jpeg&auto=webp">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="overlay">
          <div class="text">Goats</div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- partial -->
  <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the mobile browser view? Would like to see which divs the white spaces and overflowing images are.

Comment: Sure, how do i attach a screenshot?

Comment: Edit question and you should be able to include it

Answer (score 1):

Try to change media query for `.Content` that will resolve your menu issue also.

check the attached screenshot :

[browser screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMWpW.png)

Updated:

```
@media (max-device-width: 640px) and (min-device-width: 320px) {
 .Content {
    display: block !important;
    grid-gap: 10px !important;
    margin: 40px auto !important;
    box-sizing: border-box !important;
 }
}
```

Comment: I added what you did with the new media query but it is still not working for me. Can you attach the new code with the edits you made? Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: i've just added(replaced with ```@media(min-width:600px)```) width range and added ```!important``` and reload with ctrl+shift+R

Comment: I added the new media query in like you posted but it still shows up the same. Is there anything else I need to add or delete? Should I remove the @media (max-width: 699px) media query?

Comment: your ```@media (max-width: 699px)``` is working as its displayed in browser inspect section but ```@media (min-width: 600px)``` was not displayed, so thats why i changed that. try to check that why 600px media query is not working. coz i added code in ```Updated:``` which i changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting-out one of the media queries.
See how it works out, and then comment-out the other media query.
If it doesn't work, then try changing the numbers: 600 & 699.
Increase 600 or decrease the 699.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a comment and not an answer. The answer feature should not be used for comments.